# Flipping a Bitmap horizontally

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmap

I need to flip a `Bitmap` horizontally. I tried setting its `scaleX` property to `-1.0`, and that modified the `Bitmap` in such a way that I can see only a small portion of it (flipped) on the left side, instead of the whole flipped `Bitmap`. Its `x` property remained `0`. I tried the same thing using a transformation matrix, with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I posted a simple function to flip a bitmapdata object.
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/09/flipping-a-bitmapdata-image/

Here is the relevant code.

```
function flipBitmapData(original:BitmapData, axis:String = "x"):BitmapData
{
     var flipped:BitmapData = new BitmapData(original.width, original.height, true, 0);
     var matrix:Matrix
     if(axis == "x"){
          matrix = new Matrix( -1, 0, 0, 1, original.width, 0);
     } else {
          matrix = new Matrix( 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, original.height);
     }
     flipped.draw(original, matrix, null, null, null, true);
     return flipped;
}
```

If you want to flip the image in a bitmap, you can flip its bitmapdata property like so:

```
myBitmap.bitmapData = flipBitmapData(myBitmap.bitmapData, "x");
```

You can switch to a vertical flip by using "y".

Comment: I'd rather flip the `Bitmap` instead of the `BitmapData` if possible.

Comment: What is the advantage of that? A flipped bitmap will render slowly, its transform math will be reversed, and using this method, the flip is totally reversable. Is there some advantage to a flipped bitmap in your case?

Comment: Oh - also - the reason your bitmap flipping is moving the image to the left, is that the registration point for all bitmaps is the top left. If you flip the bitmapdata, your registration point is still the top left.

Comment: You're right, this is a better way than flipping the `Bitmap` itself. My problem is that the original `BitmapData` is not easy to dispose of due to some logic involved, but it's definitely worth it to find a good way to dispose of it and use this method instead. Thanks for the good solution.

Comment: Well the function above clones the bitmapdata before transforming it, so it should not cause other instances of the bitmapdata to get destroyed or altered. If you need, you can pool 2 instances of the bitmapdata to use for the orientations you need.